# Regarding send invitation to friend in Quickblox

Tags: quickblox

I have contact users from search bar of Quickblox .I want to send the invitation to selected user .
How to send the friend request to the selected friend from the user list which i get from searchbar ?
Should i maintain my own database to remote side for maintaining the friend request information??